# Added element as very first child

Tags: jquery

I have a html string:

```
var form = "<form><label >1</label><label >2</label></form>";
```

Now I want top use jquery to add another label inside the form:

```
var $form = $(form).find('form').prepend('<label >3</label>');

console.log('$form is ');
console.log($form);
```

The jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5ot1qojj/). But as you can see from the outputs, it's not added as form does is not found. How is this possible?

Comment: Since form is the top level element, just remove the `.find(...)`:  `$(form).prepend('<label >3</label>')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs on [jQuery.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

In this case, `<form>` is the top level element.  Your find is failing as there are no descendants with the tag name of form.

Because you already have the form element assigned to the variable `form`, you can change your code to:

```
$(form).prepend('<label >3</label>')
```

Which will result in:

```
<form>
    <label>3</label>
    <label>1</label>
    <label>2</label>
</form>
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ot1qojj/1/)